# How do I resolve "421 Misdirected Request"s on iOS Browsers?

Tags: ios, safari, opera, http-status-code-421

When I redirect a link from my addon domain ([booklink.id](https://booklink.id/bestbible-recom)) to my main domain ([adfontespress.com](https://adfontespress.com/connect/)), the server spits out a 421 Misdirected Request error. The error reads:

> **Misdirected Request** \ The client needs a new connection for this request as the requested host name does not match the Server Name Indication (SNI) in use for this connection.

This seems to affect iOS devices only (version 14.6 on iPhone and iPad), even with different browsers (Safari 14.6 and Opera 3.1.3). If I clear the cache, it seems to resolve the issue, but only once. When I visit the same URL a second time, it produces the same error.

What can I do to resolve the 421 error permanently?

Comment: I am facing the same problem at the moment. I can't find a solution, it's absurd how apple doesn't give a damn about these problems.